# How to use CVS on Unix

Tags: unix, cvs

I'm quite pretty new to the concept of CVS. However, I want to start using CVS and thus need to 'check-in' some scripts. I'm using a UNIX server and I know that CVS is installed, since doing a

```
cvs -v
```

Gives me the correct version number installed. Now the problem I have in is finding documentation to use CVS. Is there an online tutorial/FAQ someone can recommend. I've scoured Google for information and all I come across are posts for installing CVS ...

What I'm really looking for our sample commands taking a beginner from scratch like Logging in etc.

Comment: CVS is old and many people will say obsolete. If you want to use a modern source control management system, use git or svn.

Comment: **DO NOT USE CVS.** If you are starting work on a project that is already hosted as CVS migrate it to another SCM, (those suggested by others are good) ... If you are starting work on a group project hosted under CVS, why aren't you being trained?

Answer (score 4):

The meta-answer to your question is not to use CVS, unless you're participating in a project that's already using it.  Even the CVS maintainers, as far as I understand, don't recommend it for new projects, but recommend svn instead.  If you're being obliged to use it, then this answer isn't helpful; sorry.

If the decision is up to you, then you have alternatives:

- [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is the system which is most similar to CVS (as noted in another answer).
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is a distributed version control system, but the *distributed* features aren't hugely important if, as your question vaguely suggests, you're working on your own.
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/) has broadly the same model as Mercurial.
- There are others (including at least bazaar and darcs), but those are the big three.

All of these are heavily used in both small projects and big ones.

I now tend to recommend Mercurial to people, and that's the one I predominantly use myself.  There are holy wars possible about this, but I feel that's the one which has the best tradeoff between flexibility, good design, and usability (there's a longer version of this answer...!)

*Update:* there's a very good [Mercurial introduction by Spolsky](http://hginit.com/), which is well worth reading for rationale and pointers.

Comment: Question, what do you mean by "meta-answer"? This is informative, I'll look around and see if changing the CVS system might be an option ...

Comment: Well, by 'meta-answer' I mean that it's not answering the question you actually asked, but instead one useful question underlying it.  Perhaps 'infra-answer' would be better!

Answer (score 1):

Use svn instead, lots of documentation for that.

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer. He's not asking for an alternative.

Comment: @Dylan Lukes, it may not answer the question, but it provides information that the OP may find helpful. It probably should have been a comment, but saying that it's not helpful is a subjective point of view.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion Klaus.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... a quick Google search for `cvs tutorial` returns this as the second hit:

- http://www.linux.ie/articles/tutorials/cvs.php

I've quickly glanced over it, and Chapter 3 (*Basic CVS Usage*) starts with "Logging In" and seems to come pretty close to what you need. If you have any concrete questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I do feel quite incompetent right now! Thanks Heinzi ... I'm having a read right now.